# ng-model - getting name and value of input box

Tags: angularjs

I have an update function and a number of input boxes. Each input has an `ng-blur` attached to it so that the update function is called whenever the cursor leaves the box.

```
$scope.update = function(data) {
    console.log(data); //outputs value in the textbox
    //how can I output/access the key?
}
```

The input for `name` look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="update(user.name)"/>
```

As I need to be able to post a JSON object in the form `{"name" : "bob smith"}` what's a good way of generating the "key" of the object bearing in mind that it will differ depending on the input box that's being used at the time?

Comment: You should take a look at the ng-resource module which does what you asked once correctly configured

Comment: @Aaron I don't think that he's wondering how to post to a REST back-end, but how to get the object's key to pass along

Comment: @kuzyn "As I need to be able to post a JSON object in the form {"name" : "bob smith"}" well ng-resource excels at sending JSON formatted requests, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't need help on sending the JSON. I just need the key!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT ↓**

I have made this jsfiddle to illustrate a way to do it more cleanly & that would scale more easily: http://jsfiddle.net/kuzyn/k5bh0fq4/5/

**EDIT ↑**

Why not simply pass a second string argument? It's not a fancy way to do it but it would work:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="update(user.name, 'name')"/>
```

And

```
$scope.update = function(data, key) {
    console.log(key, data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks - this was the way I was thinking about doing it but thought there might be a "better" way.

Comment: Hey @tommyd456, check out my edit, I've updated my answer. It refactors your code a bit by dropping the ng-blur and binding it in the directive instead. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little more work but it is much more scalable.  You could make use of the `ng-form` and naming your form inputs.  By naming your form and inputs, you are creating a form reference on your scope via `$scope[form-name]`.  Each named input within that form then sets an input reference via `$scope[form-name][input-name]`.

*I'm coding this in coffeescript (to preserve my sanity, sorry)*

**form**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="update(user)"/>
    <input name="email" ng-model="user.email" ng-blur="update(user)"/>
    <input name="other" ng-model="user.other" ng-blur="update(user)"/>
</form>
```

**update & save func**

```
# key is what changed in case you need to do something special on the put call to server
$scope.save = (data, key)->

# pseudo-code
$scope.update = (data)->
    for name, input of $scope.myForm
       if input?.$dirty
           $scope.save data, name
           break
```

- docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms
- codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/LGpVGM?editors=101